# How to assign values from different dic to UIlabel

Tags: swift

I'm wondering how I can assign values of different dictionaries to a label view. My API dictionaries are:

```
languages: [
    {
    iso639_1: "ps",
    iso639_2: "pus",
    name: "Pashto",
    nativeName: "پښتو"
    },
    {
    iso639_1: "uz",
    iso639_2: "uzb",
    name: "Uzbek",
    nativeName: "Oʻzbek"
    },
    {
    iso639_1: "tk",
    iso639_2: "tuk",
    name: "Turkmen",
    nativeName: "Türkmen"
    }]
```

I made :

```
@IBOutlet weak var langues: UILabel!

func languages () {
    for eachcountry in (Countries?.languages)! {
        langues.lineBreakMode = .byCharWrapping
        langues.numberOfLines = 3
        langues.text = eachcountry.name

        print(eachcountry.name!)
    }
```

In the console it prints:

> Pashto
>   Uzbek
>   Turkmen

But in UIlabel it just shows:

> Turkmen

How can I get all three languages in my label view?

Comment: what do you mean with "in council it prints ok"?

Comment: Did you set the `numberOfLines` of the UILabel?

Comment: @Walucas OP very probably means "console"

Comment: yes I have set that to 3

Comment: You are setting several strings to the same label. Of course, the label only keeps the last one you set. It behaves as expected. Each string replaces the previous one.

Comment: @Walucas yes sorry :)

Comment: @Moritz is right. you need to concatenate  `langues.text = langues.text+ " "+ eachcountry.name`

Comment: @Moritz thanks million times it works !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your loop is parsing all dictionaries, and assign text only to last one.

Possible solution:

```
langues.text = languages.flatMap({ $0.name }).joined(separator: " ")
```

Comment: probably with `\n` if the OP wants 3 lines. Also I would set `numberOfLines = languages.count`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer yes it's working too :)